# ffmpeg - ac3 to multiple outputs

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, converters

i want to only convert the audio of a video. The video file has one ac3 5.1  audio stream and i want to make 1 mp3 256k and one AC3 384k out of it.

currently my command looks like this:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i "file-in" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v:0 copy -c:a:1 aac -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 256k -c:a:1 ac3 -b:a 384k "file1-out"
```

any idea what im missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i got it ;)

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i "file-in" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1  -c:v:0 copy -c:a:0 aac -bsf:a:0 aac_adtstoasc -ac:a:0 2 -ar 48000 -b:a:0 256k -c:a:1 ac3 -ac:a:1 6 -b:a:1 384k "file-out"
```